# Escaping brackets in a for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, brackets

how can one escape brackets inside a string went through by a for loop?

```
set a=(sample sample(2) sample 3)
for %i in %a% do echo %i
sample was unexpected at this time.
```

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping is done with the caret `^`, in this case only the closing bracket needs to be escaped.

```
@echo off
set "list=sample sample(2^) sample 3"
for %%i in (%list%) do echo %%i
```

Comment: Thank you, this finnaly works ;) ... I have an additional question: what is the difference between (%list%) vs %list% ??

Comment: Please note that in both answers you have been provided with, the respondents changed your use of outer parenteses in the creation of %a% and used them on the line underneath.

Comment: @LádíčekHaberland Compo said it: We both changed your code, as the parenthesis are syntacical part of the FOR command not of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a replacement within the loop parentheses:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "a=sample sample(2) sample 3"
For %%i In (%a:)=^)%) Do Echo=%%i
Timeout -1
```

Just remember that the format of your strings within %a% means that you have four items.